# how to add days to datetime in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have date and time format datetimepicker. I would like to add number of days to the datetime

inputdattime will be picked from datetimepicker

```
input datetime = Friday, October 23rd 2015, 12:00:00 am
 output should be if i add 2 days sunday, oct 25 2015 12:00:00 am
```

how to achieve this

```
var deal_from_date = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd  = 7;
 var date1 = deal_from_date.setDate(deal_from_date.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
```

actual Output should be

```
"dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h: mm:ss a"
 Sun Oct 25 2015 12:00:00
```

current output is:

```
     Sun Oct 25 2015 12:54:06
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setDate()` method can be used to add days to a date

```
var today=new Date('23/10/2015');
var in_a_day=new Date(today).setDate(today.getDate()+2);
```

Try this code :-

```
var d = new Date('oct 25 2015 12:00:00 pm');
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2)
alert(d);
```

> output is :- Tue Oct 27 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

Comment: how to convert oct 23rd 2015 12:00:00 pm to new Date('23/10/2015');

Comment: <script>
var d = new Date('oct 25 2015 12:00:00 pm');
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2)
alert(d);
</script>

Comment: sorry this is the input datetime Friday, October 23rd 2015, 12:00:00 am how to convert this one

Comment: found out single quote issue var get_date_from = $("#deal_val_from").val();  
        alert(get_date_from);
        
       var d = new Date('  + get_date_from  + '); 
       d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2) ;
       alert(d);

Comment: var get_date_from = $("#deal_val_from").val();  
        alert(get_date_from);
        var d = new Date('Saturday, October 24th 2015, 12:00:00 am');
        
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2) ; 
        alert(d); 
        not working